# Why my CURL response is empty?? YouTube embed

Tags: php, curl

I recently started learning curl to access YouTube API through PHP but for some reason the curl response is empty. At first the response gives me a `301 error` so i used `FOLLOW LOCATION` to follow redirects but now my request doesn't even return headers.

Here's my CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://youtube.com/oembed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
  array('url' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oorK4RPgZ8Q', 'format' => 'json')
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This code worked fine before and still works for the SoundCloud API. Could it be possible that they blocked my requests?

EDIT: Here's the response i get when i remove `FOLLOW LOCATION`

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 0
Location: https://youtube.com/oembed
Date: Fri, 02 Feb 2018 10:17:41 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: YouTube Frontend Proxy
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: you are closing curl connection before the execution of curl

Comment: @ravisachaniya Sorry, it's just a typo. FIXED

Comment: Please add the curl response you get to your question

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Edited

Comment: Is it possible that you mean `https://www.youtube.com/embed`?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/oembed - Not found!

Comment: @creyD NO
http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oorK4RPgZ8Q&format=json

Comment: There is a response and if I `curl` it I get the json...

Comment: I needed to add "www" to http://youtube.com/oembed and it worked. Silly solution but thx guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changed the url and switched 'curl_exec' with 'curl_close':

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oorK4RPgZ8Q&format=json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
/*
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
    array('url' => 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oorK4RPgZ8Q', 'format' => 'json')
));
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Edit**:

as mentioned by [creyD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7454177/creyd) and [Sewer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9125095/sewer) in the original code the line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://youtube.com/oembed');
```

should be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.youtube.com/oembed');
```

(note the added 'www')

Comment: This actually worked but why doesn't it work with http_build_query??

Comment: I needed to add "www" to http://youtube.com/oembed and it worked. Silly solution but thx man.